# Placing reference to object on global list or vector

Tags: c++, c++11

I am looking for a way to place a reference to an object on a global list or vector. I think I need something like weak_from_this() in c++17. Unfortunately I need to use c++11:(  I would like to do something like:

```
typedef std::weak_ptr<class Test> WP_Test;
vector<WP_Testl> TestVector;

class Test {
...
   void placeOnVector() { TestVector.push_back(this);}
}
```

But the compiler is unable to convert "this" to a weak_ptr.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a weak\_ptr equivalent to shared\_from\_this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38284296/is-there-a-weak-ptr-equivalent-to-shared-from-this)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: You need `std::shared_from_this()`.